# Multiple Google Maps Navigation

Tags: ios, google-maps, navigation

I feel I'm being a total idiot here but I've had a total brain fart and am new to **XCode**. I have this code (below) to open up **Google Maps** for the user to be able to navigate to a specific destination depending on which button they click. The page this is on is a fixture list, with navigation an option next to the away matches, am I correct in saying that I wouldn't need a new view controller as the google maps should just pop up anyway on button press?

Also would I need to create an `IBOutlet` in the header to create the button press `segue`. Obviously I will not put this code in the `- (void)viewDidLoad` as I only want it to show depending on the button press

```
- (void)getDirections {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D start = { (startLatitude), (startLongitude) };
    CLLocationCoordinate2D end = { (endLatitude), (endLongitude) };

    NSString *googleMapsURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&daddr=%1.6f,%1.6f", start.latitude, start.longitude, end.latitude, end.longitude];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:googleMapsURLString]];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand ok you need to open Google Maps to give directions for different matches.

First of all, you're right regarding having or not a new view controller, you don't need to create a new view controller, since you're calling

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:googleMapsURLString]];
```

And this should open GoogleMaps to display directions given your origin & destinations coordinates are OK. If there is no possible direction GoogleMaps still will open and will tell you no directions were found.

What you should do is:

1. Keep an array with your matches destination coordinates.
2. Be aware of your current coordinates (if you're trying to provide directions from your current position to the match's place).
3. Create an IBAction to handle the buttons press action, as following:

   -(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {//YOUR CODE TO OPEN URL HERE};
4. According to the sender you can detect what button was pressed. You have different ways to do that. One possible way is to add a tag to each button from Interface Builder and later read the tag to determine which button was pressed. Another alternative if you have a fixed amount of button, say 3 for example is to create IBOutlets for each button and compare 'sender' with your IBOutlet. Once you know which button is the sender for the buttonPressed IBAction you need to recover the coordinates associated with that button / match.
5. Remember to link your touch up inside events on your buttons with the IBAction.
6. If you choose to create an IBOutlet for every button remember to link the buttons with its outlet.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! this definitely does help, it seems I have made this into something more difficult than it really is. The start location will be the same (the home team ground) every time. And like you suggested there is a fixed amount of buttons, 6 in total so having 6 different IBOutlets seems the best solution. So every button will have the same start coordinates, just different end ones. Where would I put the destination coordinates? Still suggest an array? –

Comment: Good to know it helps :), Yes, you could use an array (mapping your coordinates to NSValues), or you could simply have 6 coordinates variables, or to make the code reusable and POO compliance you could create a model object, probably called Club… or Match… that could have a name, a latitude, a longitude … so you would have an array of Matches for example… every position of the array mapped to a button… that would allow you to create new Match objects in the future and extend your app.

Comment: I think I'm going to stick to 6 different coordinate variables and have the -(void)getDirections for each of the destinations, changing the end destination every time. how would the IBOulet look? having problems making the button call the code to display google maps. not sure where I should be dragging the touch up inside event